# Layout issue with progress bar in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating an item that gets a list of tweets for a user. While the tweets are loaded, the page shows a progress bar against the bottom of a tile. In other words, I am creating a tile that looks something like this:

```
+--------------+
|              |
|    [logo]    |
|              |
||||||||       |
+--------------+
```

The consecutive `|` represents the progress bar. The progress bar should take up the full width of the bottom and be aligned flush against the bottom border of the tile. However, my tiles render like this:

```
+--------------+
|              |
|  [logo]      |
|              |
|  ||||||||||  |
+--------------+
```

The logo is left-aligned instead of centered. The progress bar is centered and takes up the full width. There is some padding, which I don't want.

When I look at the code below, I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .choice {
    border: solid 1px #2d2d2d;
    color: #2d2d2d;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    clear:both;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
  }
</style>

<div class="choice">
  <div class="fa fa-twitter"></div>
  <progress class="tweet-progress mb-0" value="50" min="0" max="100"></progress>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in your CSS affects the `<div>` you're loading your Font Awesome icon into.  There is nothing telling it to be centered or to be 100% width.  Addressing that should get the results you expect.

```css
.choice {
    border: solid 1px #2d2d2d;
    color: #2d2d2d;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    clear:both;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
  }
  
  .fa {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="choice">
  <div class="fa fa-twitter"></div>
  <progress class="tweet-progress mb-0" value="50" min="0" max="100"></progress>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. However, the progress bar isn't against the left, right, and bottom borders. There's still padding there, which I don't get.

Comment: Uh... your `.choice` wrapper has `padding: 16px 32px` declared.  That applies 16px to the top/bottom and 32px to the left/right.

Answer (score 0):

The padding is coming from the choice, so if you remove that, give the choice a set height and width and position the progress absolutely, you can make it flush with the bottom, while width:100% makes it take up the whole width of choice.

```css
.choice {
  border: solid 1px #2d2d2d;
    color: #2d2d2d;
    /* padding: 16px 32px; */
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 130px;
    height: 35px;
  }
  
  .fa {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  progress{
      width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -4px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="choice">
  <div class="fa fa-twitter"></div>
  <progress class="tweet-progress mb-0" value="50" min="0" max="100"></progress>
</div>
```